# Local asymptotical stability for an ODE

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider a system:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ a x_1 + b x_1^2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
with $a < 0$ and $b\ne0$. My question is whether the equilibrium point $x=0$ is a locally asymptotically stable equilibrium point. I tried some Lyapunov functions, for example:
$$ V = -\frac{a}{2} x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_2^2 - \frac{b}{3}x_1^3 $$
give 
$$ L_f V = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}f = 0,$$
hence the Lyapunov-stability, but not asymptotic stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $dV/dt = 0$ says that the trajectories in the $x_1,x_2$ plane lie on the curves $V = \text{constant}$.  The origin is a strict local minimum of
$V$, so near the origin these form closed curves around the origin.
A solution starting near the origin will not approach the origin, but will stay on such a curve.  Therefore the equilibrium is a center: stable, but not asymptotically stable.

From another point of view, the lack of asymptotic stability is the result of the invariance of the system under the symmetry $x_1 \to x_1$, $x_2 \to -x_2$, $t \to -t$.  If such a system is started at, say, $x_1 = p, x_2 = 0, t = 0$, and reaches $x_2 = 0$ again at $x_1 = q, t = T$, then by symmetry we will have $(x_1(T+t),x_2(T+t)) = (x_1(T-t),-x_2(T-t))$, so that at $t=2T$ it comes back to $x_1 = p, x_2 = 0$, and will continue in a closed orbit of period $2T$.